# Jenkins Pipeline Conditional Execution By Branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a pipeline that will vary its behavior based on the branch being edited.

I am using gitflow and have a branch named

> feature/my-feature

My pipeline has

```
    when {
        anyof { branch 'develop'; branch '.*feature.*'}
   }
   ... some steps...
```

The problem is that when I run the pipeline my condition evaluates to false and my step is not run. I have tried a few different variations using both regex and Glob syntax: 'feature*', '.*feature', '*feature*' but cannot seem to get a match.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Regex syntax (`.*`), but the branch condition only works with [Glob syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). So it should work using `branch '*feature*'`.

Comment: I tried Glob syntax too and I am still getting the same results.